# MaterialCSS Table accordion

Tags: html, css, materialize

Im trying to create an accordion effect in my table using material css. They do have a [collapsible](http://materializecss.com/collapsible.html) class. However using that with a table is not giving me the desired affect. Code: (**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/isharief318/pen/QKNZLV)**)

```
<table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
              <th data-field="id">Name</th>
              <th data-field="name">Item Name</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
          <td>
            <p class="table-metric-color">Alex</p>
          </td>
          <td>
            <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="collapsible-header">Details</a>
                <p class="collapsible-body white"><code> Details here</code></p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

I am aiming for something like [this](http://codepen.io/isharief318/pen/YpXoeg?editors=1010), which I got using bootstrap css. Any way to replicate this using material css?

Answer (score 1):

You should include jquery first, and initialize the collapsible as following :

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.collapsible').collapsible();
  });
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XNmMLL?editors=1111

Comment: Ive already tried it and got it to work. However I am aiming for something more like this - http://codepen.io/isharief318/full/YpXoeg/ where on click the data appears as a separate row